# How to create a Web Setup project in VS 2010 for a MVC2 application?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, web-setup-project

I need help to create a Web Setup project for an MVC2 application I made at home, since I have VS 2010 there and I need to show people at the office, who have VS 2008 + sp1 + MVC2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a web setup project to your solution:

[image]

Comment: Yes I did that but after that I looked at this http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/K18198.aspx, but in step 1 c) I dont get content files

Answer (score 2):

Create a web setup project;

Add project output
 - select your web project 
 - select primary output
 - click ok

Add project output again
 - select your web project
 - select content files
 - click ok

Answer (score 1):

Customize it by adding Custom Actions such as IIS version or DB connection string. More info here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/15/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005.aspx