# How to create an MSI installer package for an ASP.Net website?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How do I create an MSI installer package for an ASP.Net website ?

Can anyone help me with a good link?

Mosty of the articles just presents the solution for windows applications.

I get this Error by using Add Deployment Project: when merging assemblies aspnet_merge. in Deploy Project.
http://codeissue.com/articles/a04df930da62eb1/create-asp-net-deployment-package-using-web-deployment-and-web-setup-project

ERROR: Error    35  An error occurred when merging assemblies: ILMerge.Merge: ERROR!!: Duplicate type 'SatmapSkillReport' found in assembly 'App_Web_4fgmsrtw'. Project_deploy  aspnet_merge    1   1

Comment: Even if sound cool, how many stuff you going to setup automatically ? DNS ?, Permissions ? Copy Files ? Create and install the database ? email setup ?, SSL security setup ? ftp setup ?, web statistics setup ? pool install and permissions...

Comment: @Ravi actually you can. I used it with web deploy projects wherein the output of the web deploy project gets included in the web setup project.

Comment: @Aristos, yep, it is cool. You can even include your own logo, company name, etc. during the installation. Setup install location, copy files, run database scripts, check of dependencies (existence of framework version, maybe other apps?), app pool creation, registry values/setting..

Comment: First compile website to specific location in postBuild Event like -- 
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /S -p "website path" d:\test -f -u -fixednames                and follow these link as well to understand -- http://odetocode.com/articles/417.aspx
-- http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ASP/Precompiling.html   --- http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/May/14/New-Compilation-Modes-in-ASPNET-20     --- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383481/Editing-an-MSI-Database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution my self.!

you can follow link.

**[1]: [Can't rename MSI afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542919/cant-rename-msi-afterwards)**

and for Help:

**[2]: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/**

Answer (score 8):

It is actually possible but please note that my experience with this was with Visual Studio 2008. I haven't tried this on Visual Studio 2010 or 2012.

1. In VS2008, click on `File` > `Add` > `New Project`
2. In `Add New Project` dialog, select `Other Project Types` > `Setup and Deployment` > `Web Setup Project`
3. From there you can right-click on the project in the solution explorer and click `View` to see the user interfaces, launch conditions, registry settings, etc. or in `Properties` to set the virtual directory name. You can also include the output files of any project or your main project to be deployed.

If you configure this correctly and build that project, the output is an MSI installer file. When you use this MSI installer file, you can use `Add/Remove Programs` (win xp) or `Programs and Features` (win7).

I guess you can setup DNS, permissions, run a database creation script, with the various possible configurations available.

[A good guide with a lot of screenshots here](http://dataerror.blogspot.com/2010/06/creating-web-setup-project-for-aspnet.html)

**UPDATE**

[Web deployment project is not available in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229582/will-web-deployment-projects-still-be-available-in-visual-studio-2012)

[Web deployment project is available in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524634/how-to-create-a-web-setup-project-in-vs-2010-for-a-mvc2-application)